# Object Moves With Mouse (Python)

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

The following line of code, I have borrowed as an example to use. What it does is it takes a string and prints it out in pygame, and the line will follow wherever the mouse goes. I simply was wondering how to change the string line for a draw.circle, I keep getting an error. Cheers! Code Below, the string in question is the one saying, "the last button pressed is".

```
from pygame import * 
init()
size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = display.set_mode(size)
button = 0
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 255, 255)
font = font.SysFont("Times New Roman",30)

def drawScene(screen, mx, my, button):
    draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, width, height))
    # Draw circle if the left mouse button is down.
    string = "The last button pressed is " + str(button) + "."
    text = font.render(string, 1, RED)
    size = font.size(string)
    screen.blit(text, Rect(mx, my, size[0], size[1]))
    display.flip()

running = True
myClock = time.Clock()

mx = my = 0
# Game Loop
while running:
    for evnt in event.get():             # checks all events that happen
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx, my = evnt.pos          
            button = evnt.button
        if evnt.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mx, my = evnt.pos
    drawScene(screen, mx, my, button)
    myClock.tick(60)                     # waits long enough to have 60 fps

quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will draw a 5 pixel radius circle at mx, my:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (mx, my), 5)
```